# Slim v2 Hello World broken or badly explained

Tags: php, slim

the code from http://docs.slimframework.com/start/get-started/#hello-world leaves open many questions, I wonder why they explained it so badly? Or is it me missing something?

First of all, how do I run a test of the app?

well I open

`http://localhost/myapp/hello/dirk`

404 FOF error

> The requested URL /myapp/hello/dirk was not found on this server.

Cool

really simple to set up

this is my index.php

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});
$app->run();
?>
```

**EDIT**

clearly the "Getting started" of Slim is broken / incomplete.

If you, by accident click on the url rewrite chapter, you will read

> I strongly encourage you to use a web server that supports URL
>   rewriting; this will let you enjoy clean, human-friendly URLs with
>   your Slim application.

well no, it is not encouraged, it just plain does not work if you don't do it (the hello world). See my answer.

Comment: It's not really a problem with Slim Framework.  They're assuming that you can run a basic PHP Hello World script, which really is a very reasonable basic requirement.  In this case, just create a file with the following contents and try to get it to show up in your browser, then go back to the Slim tutorial once you're successful: `<?php echo "Hello, world!";`

Comment: lol @Ghedipunk it is running of course. The thing they don't explain is why should `index.php` from `/myapp/` be called at all, when opening `/myapp/foo/bar` . And there you go, it does not get called

Comment: even https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-slim-framework-on-ubuntu-14-04 did not help me

Comment: @Toskan the problem could be your URL address. Router is looking for exact url given in method `$app->get()`. Slim is looking for route `/hello/dirk` when you're giving him `/myapp/hello/dirk`. Maybe try to create [VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) for your dev environment.

Comment: I am able to run this: `$app->get('/', function () {
    echo "easy hello world";
});` but not `$app->get('/t2/', function () {
    echo "easy2 hello world";
});` and as stated before, it does not really surprise really does it?

Comment: @GrzegorzGajda i can move it to the root folder, still won't work.

Comment: @Toskan check if you have a proper `.htaccess` file in directory with `index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

so after following:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-slim-framework-on-ubuntu-14-04

Congratulations, I hope the guy who wrote the getting started (the official slim 2 one), is gonna hit his toe against a door for his laziness.

So you have to add a .htaccess on the level of the index.php

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});

$app->get('/', function () {
    echo "Thanks for not including essential info to the getting started";
});
$app->run();
?>
```

Comment: the instructions are perfectly clear: http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/#without-url-rewriting

Comment: @r3wt oh holy cow! you found somewhere in their manual a link to a page giving an example that works? hey, cool stuff man! But open their docs, click on "Get started" and guess what, it does NOT get you started.

Comment: I know, i went through it about a year ago or so. Bonus Points: Their recommended configuration for NGINX will result in $_GET always being empty.